# how to access vista system remotely using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I tried to access xp to vista system manually, its working,but programatically how to do it ?

like,by selecting view workgroup computers in network tasks and click one computer in workgroup computers.it shows connect to "system name" window, contains username and password 
if i enter username and password.the seleted computer will able to access in registry 
otherwise i can't able to access that selected system.

how to do this manual process in vb.net coding? is it possible or not?

please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenRemoteBaseKey to access the remote registry but before that you need to impersonate an account with the correct access rights using WindowsIdentity.Impersonate.

The following MSDN link contains a complete sample to login as a different user programmatically:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx

Comment: Thank u,
To access vista system,OpenRemoteBaseKey is not working.
then how to impersonate an account  in vista os remotely

Comment: The MSDN link contains a sample application that tells you how to impersonate another account that has access to the remote computer so you have to do that first and then call OpenRemoteBaseKey.

Comment: THANK U,Its working.
Is it possible by giving system name or ip address only

Comment: I'm not sure if it works with IP Address, but otherwise just use GetHostEntry to get the name as in:  
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1").HostName

Comment: how to get  username,password of remote systems? (vista and xp),
Is it possible? Please help me

Comment: Hopefully you already have a username and password of an account on the remote system otherwise you have to ask the owner of that system to provide them to you.

Comment: how to get os version of remote computer using computer name or ip address?

Comment: You might want to start new questions to get better answers, but a short answer would probably be to look into WMI.